# Immediate validation check on input to edittext field(integer type)

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, android-input-method

I want to validate the input , if the value inputted is in between 9 to 50 the input text is valid(toast) else toast invalid.
The problem I am facing is when I enter some integer and than clear/erase the text field to nothing ,the app crashes..
main activity code here:

```
v1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               /* int var1,var2;
                var1=Integer.parseInt(v1.getText().toString());
                var2=Integer.parseInt(v2.getText().toString());

                if (var1<9 && var2>50){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"invalid input ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
/*

                int var1,var2;
                var1=Integer.parseInt(v1.getText().toString());
                var2=Integer.parseInt(v2.getText().toString());
*/
//                String var1=v1.getText().toString();




               /* String inpt="";
                *//*for (int i = start;i<=before;i++){

                    inpt= s + inpt;

                }

*//*
//                for(String reslt:s.length())
                var1=Integer.parseInt(inpt);
*/


    int var1=0;

    var1 = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());


    if (var1 < 9 || var1 > 50) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "invalid input ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valid ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



            }
        });
```

CRASH LOG is as :

```
11-07 16:11:49.521 27518-27518/com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar, PID: 27518
                                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                 at com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:82)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7894)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7954)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9776)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:216)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
                                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)
                                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)
                                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)
                                                                                 at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5930)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5743)
                                                                                 at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2651)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8412)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1496)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2432)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1738)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2757)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2321)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4273)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4227)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3913)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6165)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6110)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3533)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Loope
```

11-07 16:11:49.551 27518-27518/com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar V/Process: killProcess [27518] Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:99 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690  
11-07 16:11:49.551 27518-27518/com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27518 SIG: 9

Comment: add your crash log here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

So when we convert `String` to `int` ,we should know that `String` is null or not.

When you use `TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) ? 0 : s.toString()` in your code , if `s.toString()` is null , it will return `0` .It will not cause `NumberFormatException` .And if `s.toString()` is not null ,it will return normal .

You should judge that `s.toString` is null or not.

Use `var1 = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) ? 0 : s.toString());` in your code .

```
var1 = Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) ? 0 : s.toString());
if (var1 < 9 || var1 > 50) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "invalid input ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valid ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calling Integer.parseInt() code converts your String variable to Integer one and "" string from EditText is not valid one. You should check if your input string is not equal "" before calling Integer.parseInt().

BTW. Better practice is writing your custom input filter, that allows to use only numbers in range of 9 - 50

Comment: i'm beginner .. so custom input filter would be quite heavy for now, but i'll go through it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple check was required in onTextChanged(override method), to check whether the field is empty or not.
The working code is as follows:

```
if(s.length()>0) {


            int var1 = 0;

            var1 = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());


            if (var1 < 9 || var1 > 50) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "invalid input ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valid ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }else {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FIELD EMPTY ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```